# can't publish message to SNS queue from EventBridge

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-sns, aws-event-bridge

Assume an SNS topic that is configured with a "default" access policy as follows:

```
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Id": "__default_policy_ID",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "__default_statement_ID",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": [
        "SNS:GetTopicAttributes",
        "SNS:SetTopicAttributes",
        "SNS:AddPermission",
        "SNS:RemovePermission",
        "SNS:DeleteTopic",
        "SNS:Subscribe",
        "SNS:ListSubscriptionsByTopic",
        "SNS:Publish"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:############:NotificationTopic-test",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "AWS:SourceOwner": "############"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

CloudWatch alarms CAN publish to this topic.
An EventBridge rule CANNOT publish to this topic.

Does EventBridge require an SNS access policy with "Principal": {"Service": "events.amazonaws.com"} whereas CloudWatch does not?  If so, why?

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind this issue is that AWS is not consistent. Read [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-access-policy-use-cases.html#:%7E:text=Manager%20Incident%20Manager-,aws%3ASourceAccount%20versus%20aws%3ASourceOwner,SourceOwner%20and%20a%20list%20of%20AWS%20services%20that%20support%20that%20condition.,-Allow%20accounts%20in).
CW Alarms seems to send a `AWS:SourceOwner` value to sns and EventBridge Rules a `aws:SourceAccount`. So in your case you need to change the condition to `aws:SourceAccount`

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you will need to add events.amazonaws.com service with permission to publish, like this:

```
{
  "Sid": "AWSEvents_xxxxxxxxxx",
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Principal": {
    "Service": "events.amazonaws.com"
  },
  "Action": "sns:Publish",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxx:your-eventbridge-topic"
}
```

There is a [troubleshooting guide](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/sns-not-getting-eventbridge-notification/) that might also be helpful in setting that up.

Comment: thank you.  do you know why a service principle is needed for eventbridge but not for cloudwatch?

Comment: Cloudwatch may be a special case, possibly because of its monitoring capabilities, whereas EventBridge needs to be treated like any other service.